# Pad a binary String equal to zero ("0") with leading zeros in Java

Tags: java, string

```
Integer.toBinaryString(data)
```

gives me a binary String representation of my array data.

However I would like a simple way to add leading zeros to it, since a byte array equal to zero gives me a "0" String.

I'd like a one-liner like this:

```
String dataStr = Integer.toBinaryString(data).equals("0") ? String.format(format, Integer.toBinaryString(data)) : Integer.toBinaryString(data);
```

Is `String.format()` the correct approach? If yes, what `format` String should I use?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: The `data` array is of dynamic length, so should the number of leading zeros.

Comment: How long do you want the string?

Comment: thats what I was about to say. my array is of dynamic size, so the Pattern should too...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For padding with, say, 5 leading zeroes, this will work:

```
String.format("%5s", Integer.toBinaryString(data)).replace(' ', '0');
```

You didn't specify the expected length of the string, in the sample code above I used 5, replace it with the proper value.

**EDIT**

I just noticed the comments. Sure you can build the pattern dynamically, but at some point you *have to* know the maximum expected size, depending on your problem, you'll know how to determine the value:

```
String formatPattern = "%" + maximumExpectedSize + "s";
```

Comment: The dynamic padding will only add spaces.

Comment: @erickson correct, that's why I replace spaces with '0'. It's ok since  `toBinaryString()` doesn't return spaces

Comment: Okay, I see, that's just the pattern to be used in the first expression.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "padding with 5 leading zeros" but "padding with zeros to make this 5-digit binary string"

Answer (score 2):

This is what you asked for—padding is added *only* when the value is zero.

```
String s = (data == 0) ? String.format("%0" + len + 'd', 0) : Integer.toBinaryString(data);
```

If what you *really* want is for all binary values to be padded so that they are the same length, I use something like this:

```
String pad = String.format("%0" + len + 'd', 0);
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(data);
s = pad.substring(s.length()) + s;
```

Using `String.format()` directly would be the best, but it only supports decimal, hexadecimal, and octal, not binary.

Answer (score 1):

You could override that function in your own class:

```
    public static String toBinaryString(int x){

        byte[] b = new byte[32]; // 32 bits per int
        int pos = 0;        
        do{
            x = x >> 1; // /2
            b[31-pos++] = (byte)(x % 2);
        }while(x > 0);

        return Arrays.toString(b);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

would this satisfy your needs?

```
String dataStr = data == 0 ? "00" +   Integer.toBinaryString(data)  : Integer.toBinaryString(data);
```

edit: noticed the comment about dynamic length:
probably some of the other answers are more suited:)

Answer (score 0):

This, in concept, is almost same as @Óscar López answer, but different methods are used, so i thought i should post it. Hope this is fine.

1] Building the format string

```
    String format = "%0" + totalDigits + "d";
```

2] Integer to Binary Conversion

```
    String dataStr = Integer.toBinaryString(data);
```

3] Padding with Leading Zeros

```
    dataStr = String.format(format, new Integer(dataStr));
```

The major difference here is the 3rd step. I believe, its actually a hack.
@erickson is right in `String.format()` not supporting binary, hence, i converted the binary number to an integer (not its equivalent), i.e., "100" will be converted to hundred (100), not four(4). I then used normal formatting.

Not sure about how much optimized this code is, but, i think its more easy to read, but, maybe, its just me.

EDIT
1] Buffer Over-run is possible for longer binary strings. `Long` can be used, but, even that has limitations.
2] `BigInteger` can be used, but, I'm sure, it will be the costliest at runtime compared to all the other methods.
So, it seems, unless only shorter binary strings are expected, `replace()` is the better method.

Seniors,
please correct me if I'm wrong.
Thanks.