# How to get all possible matches of std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl

I would like to find all possible matches of regex, how is it possible?

```
regex rx("(2|25)");
string s = "2225";
for (sregex_iterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), rx), end; it != end; ++it) {
    cout << it->position() << ": " << it->str() << endl;
}
```

Gives output:

```
0: 2
1: 2
2: 25
```

But can't find third `2: 2` exactly. I prefer to use regex because of `O(n)` complexity for searching several tokens at same time.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe split token list to non-prefixable lists and create several regexes? For example: `(2|4|25|45|251|455|267)` => `(2|4)`, `(25|45|267)`, `(251|455)` This will grow complexity to something like `O(n log(m))`

**UPDATE 2:**

Please, provide short STL-based algorithm of splitting token vector to non-prefixable vectors to answer this question.

Comment: If you only want matches on the `2` why do you use `|25` as part of your regex?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I wanna discover all 4 matches for `O(n)` complexity :)

Comment: I believe you cannot match the same character in two different matching groups (ie. you won't be able to match the `2` as part of `25` but also on its own).

Comment: I believe this problems can only be done with two regular expressions. I tested some implementations other than std::regex, and they matches three "2" and no "25". It seems that no regex implementations give up what  has been matched and try to find other way to match it.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I hope it is possible without creating `m` regexes for each token. Maybe split token list to non-prefixable lists and create several regexes?

Comment: @k06a In which case, why use regex? This turns into a simple text search problem.

Comment: @Phylogenesis regex can give me `O(n)` complexity for searching several tokens simultaneously.

Comment: use boost regex with lookaround?

Comment: Regex will not just reduce algorithmic complexity. You are having to check whether each of `n` characters are the start of `m` different strings. You are going to struggle to find an algorithm that works better than `O(nm)` in general by the nature of your search space (the best you can really hope for is to do some pre-calculation to find matching prefixes).

Comment: @Atomic_alarm I thought std regex is a little bit changed boost regex, is not it?

Comment: @k06a, unfortunately no. 
it is an opportunity that you need is not supported. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538687/using-regex-lookbehinds-in-c11

Comment: @k06a From your edit, I'm not sure you really understand algorithmic complexity. You can reduce the number of passes you need to perform, but each pass is doing more work. Searching for `(2|4)` will look for both 2s and 4s in a single pass, but will require twice the amount of work to do so. It doesn't actually reduce the complexity.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I hope std regex uses DFA. So it should be O(n) with any complex expression.

Comment: A DFA does not reduce the complexity of testing a match to `O(1)`. It depends the number of strings you're matching, but also on the similarity of the strings you're matching (which you're proposing to actually reduce by pulling strings with matching prefixes into separate passes). Doing what you're doing is still pretty close to `O(nm)` complexity.

Comment: @Phylogenesis DFA is automata with single state at any moment. So transition from state to state is just `O(1)` for every input char. Isn't it?

Comment: If you only want to match a single pattern. You need multiple state transitions if you want to match multiple patterns.

Comment: @Phylogenesis thats why regex libraries constructs NFA from expression and then transforms it to DFA to achieve real `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but the new answer might help you out for the _regex_ part of your problem. Regarding algorithmic complexity, not much to note, but it does gets progressively quicker to search through the string after each match, as the string to search through reduces in length after removing previously matched text. Keep in mind the regex engine moves from left-to-right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a regular expression, how would I generate all strings that match it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080789/given-a-regular-expression-how-would-i-generate-all-strings-that-match-it)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it's possible with an iterator and a single regexp. Here's how it works.

Your regexp searches for a substring that is either "2" *or* "25". Now, you start the search with `sregex_iterator`. It starts with the first symbol of the string, and tries to find match with your regular expression. If there is a match, it is "recorded", and the iterator is advanced to the position after the match. If there is no match, the iterator is advanced 1 position forward. This process continues until the end of the string is reached.

Now, each time it finds a match it will try to find the best (i.e., longest) match from your regular expression. So if a substring matches both `2` and `25`, it will take `25` since it's longer. So I'd say you need 2 regular expressions.

Comment: Help me to avoid `m` regular expression, each one will contain only 1 token :) Complexity grows to `O(nm)` :(

Comment: I don't think it actually matches the longest match, it matches the *first* match. The order of the alternates matters: see this [example](http://ideone.com/Jgq9pZ).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, that's fascinating because on my machine the result is exactly the opposite (`rx1` finds `2 2 25` and `rx2` finds `2 2 2`)

Comment: `std::(basic_)regex` should default to using ECMAScript rules if I'm not mistaken, which should prefer the first matching alternative. If you use extended / POSIX it will prefer the longer one IIRC. Try this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79388d279f74ce52

Comment: @k06a, you can group them if the subexpressions are not prefixes of any other subexpressions, e.g. you can group `3|45` because `3` is not a prefix of `45`

Comment: @melak47 looks like ECMA works different :) cpp.sh/7qni

Comment: This seems to [have changed since gcc 5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f29ba636b098818)

Comment: If I change the OPs original regexp to `regex rx("(25|2)");`, it finds `2,2,2`. I fail to understand the logic here honestly

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall looks like order should not me important at all :) But it is terrible if order impacts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't obtain the third '2', because regexes always return the longest match. In order to get "all the possible matches" you need to run the query two times, since 2 is contained in 25.