# Bit level operations, get a bit from a short value

Tags: java, integer, bit, 16-bit

I'm trying to get the following result `00000000000000101` from this input `5`.

This my code and it doesn't make sense:

```
public static int get16Bits(int x)
    {
        System.out.println((x & 0xffff) - ((x & 0x8000) << 1));
        return (x & 0xffff) - ((x & 0x8000) << 1);

    }
```

How i can get the *16bits* of integer value?

Comment: Which *16bits*  do you mean? Your question doesn't seem to make much sense. `00000000000000101` is just the binary representation of `5` with some leading zeros. So for this example input your method should just return the input as far as I guess.

Comment: Try this: `String.format("%016d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(x)))`

Comment: @procrastinator This is what he wants? Nice, if you guessed correctly you should post an answer, I will upvote.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker yup, i need the 16 bits binary.

Comment: @Oleg that's what I understood from the problem. Ain't sure whether they meant the same or different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try this code below, we will use for loop :

```
public void getBits(int number){

      String bits = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
          bits = (number & 1) + bits;
          number >>= 1;
      }
      System.out.println("The bits are " + bits);
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try changing your return statement a bit:

```
    public static String get16Bits(int x)
    {
        return (String.format("%016d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(x))));

    }
```

This should help you.

Comment: yup it's working. but not perfect...
what about negative numbers ? 
also i need to get result without methods.

Comment: change your method signature or your return type, because it does not compile.

Comment: @android without using any of the methods, it'd be difficult.

Comment: @procrastinator it would be mode easier and much funny and more useful.

Answer (score 6):

The first part is self-explanatory: the upper 16 bits are removed with `& 0xffff` masking.

Subtracting `(x & 0x8000) << 1` is a trick that keeps the proper sign of the 16-bit number in the 32-bit result: for example, `0xffff`, a -1 in 16-bit representation, gets converted to `0xffffffff`, which is also -1 in 32-bit representation. This is better than using a conditional, because it is branch-free.

Another trick that you could use is

```
(((x & 0xFFFF) << 16) >> 16)
```

This lets the sign bit of 16-bit number "touch" the sign bit of 32-bit number, letting the right shift to sign-extend the result.

**Note:** If you are looking for a binary `String` representation of the number, only `x & 0xffff` masking is necessary, because the upper 16 bits are dropped from the string result anyway. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8457734/335858) explains how to obtain a binary representation of an integer with the appropriate number of leading zeros.

Comment: Well, thanks for help, but it's still not perfect solution...! negative numbers didn't converted.

Comment: @android Could you provide an example of a negative number that failed to convert?

Comment: -5  would be 1111111111111011

Comment: @android That's the proper two's complement representation of negative five, though: you invert `0000000000000101` which becomes `1111111111111010`, and add `1` to the result, producing `1111111111111011`

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(5)).replace(' ', '0')
```